# Pickle not saving in to file

Tags: python, file, pickle, inventory

So, i'm coding an discord bot for playing rpg with my friends, and i writed something about 1,3k lines, using pickle and some other librarys, and until my last function it's worked very well, but in this " Atualizar_inventario()" the pickle just dont' save my list " ITEM " in my " Abrir_Para_Escrita", and i dont have any ideia why.

```
def Autualizar_inventario():

# Booleano para quebrar o looping quando quisermos sair
Sair = False



# Variavel que vai receber nome para comparação
Nome = input("Qual inventario você deseja atualizar?")

print(Nome)
#Abrir arquivo para leitura
Abrir_Inv = open(f"Inventario/{Nome}.pickle", "rb")
Ler_Inv = pickle.load(Abrir_Inv)

# Lista que vai receber os itens que vamos adicionar depois
Item = [Ler_Inv]


# Sender_ID vai servir para só o dono do inventario poder alteralo 
Sender_ID = "Jorge" # Yamo altera essa string pra um comando que recebe o ID do usuario 

# Se o sender ID for o mesmo que o primeiro parametro " QUE NO CASO SERA O ID"
# if vai ser ativado, nos botando em um looping onde adicionaremos os itens
if Sender_ID == Ler_Inv[0] : # or Sender_ID == "350364616657862679"  < -- Codigo para reconhecer o meu discord
    
    while Sair == False:
        
        Input_Item = input("Escreva o nome do item")
        
        # Comando para sair do inventario
        if Input_Item == "sair" or Input_Item == "Sair" or Input_Item == "SAIR":
            break
        

        # Se sair não for ativado começam as etapas de salvar os novos itens no inventario
        else : 

            # Adiciona o item digitado pelo usuario na lista " ITEM "
            Item.append(Input_Item)
            
            # Mostra os parametros // serve apenas para configuração 
            print("printando item = ", Item)
            
            Abrir_Para_Escrita = open(f"Inventario/{Nome}.pickle", 'wb')
            pickle.dump(Item, Abrir_Para_Escrita)
            Abrir_Para_Escrita.close()
            
            print("printando arquivo ", Ler_Inv)
```

Comment: How do you know that the list is not saved?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I'm printing the file to see what is in it in the last line of the code, and it return only te " SENDER_ID "

Comment: "Ler_Inv" is loaded from pickle file and then not modified until printing. It can't reflect changes to the file happening after loading.